# Using a ListIterator

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I have an assignment I am having a hard time completing. It is a two part lab which demonstrates the LinkedList and Queue classes. I have to use the offer() method and an iterator to complete the part I am having issues with. I wrote a class called BasketBallPlayer and added several objects of that type to a linkedList using add. Then I used an iterator to list those objects. However, when I use the offer() method, I am unable to list the objects with my code. 
This is the snippet which throws a concurrent modification exception

```
LinkedList<BasketBallPlayer> list = 
    new LinkedList<BasketBallPlayer>();
    Iterator listIterator = list.iterator();
    list.offer(kyrie);
    list.offer(kat) ;
    list.offer(julius);
    list.offer(kawhi) ; 
    list.offer(devin);

    while(listIterator.hasNext())
        System.out.println(listIterator.next());
```

This is the entire class from that snippet.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Queue {


    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        BasketBallPlayer kyrie = new BasketBallPlayer(
        "Kyrie Irving", 1, "Cavaliers");
        BasketBallPlayer kat = new BasketBallPlayer(
        "Karl Anthony Towns", 5, "Timberwolves");
        BasketBallPlayer julius = new BasketBallPlayer(
        "Julius Randle", "Power Forward", "Lakers");
        BasketBallPlayer kawhi = new BasketBallPlayer(
        "Kawhi Leanord", "Small Forward", "Spurs");
        BasketBallPlayer devin = new BasketBallPlayer(
        "Devin Booker", "Shooting Guard", "Suns");
        System.out.println(kyrie);

        LinkedList<BasketBallPlayer> list = 
        new LinkedList<BasketBallPlayer>();
        Iterator listIterator = list.iterator();
        list.offer(kyrie);
        list.offer(kat) ;
        list.offer(julius);
        list.offer(kawhi) ; 
        list.offer(devin);
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Object player = listIterator.next();
            System.out.println(player);
        }

        System.out.println("Which player is first?");
        System.out.println(list.peek());
        for(Object player: list)
        {
            System.out.println(list.getFirst());
            list.poll();
        }

    }
}
```

lastly, the BasketballPlayer class. This class contains part 1 of the assignment. Here I demonstrate linkedList methods. This part works. I am unsure why the iterator in part 1 is not throwing exceptions while the iterator in part 2 is despite being used almost exactly the same. Can anyone educate me on how to correct my mistake?

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class BasketBallPlayer
{
    private String name = "" , position = ""; String team = "";
    private int positionNumber = 0;
    public BasketBallPlayer()
    {
        name = "noName";
        position = "noPosition";
        team = "noTeam";
        positionNumber = 0;
    }
    public BasketBallPlayer(String playersName,  int thePositionNumber,
                             String theTeam)
    {


setName(playersName); setPositionNumber(thePositionNumber);
        setTeam(theTeam);
    }
    public BasketBallPlayer(String playersName, String playersPosition,
                            String theTeam)
    {
        setName(playersName);
        setPosition(playersPosition);
        setTeam(theTeam

);
    }
    public void setName(String theName)
    {
        this.name = theName;
    }
    public void setTeam(String theTeam)
    {
        this.team = theTeam;
    }
    public void setPosition(String playerPosition)
    {
    this.position = playerPosition;
    if(playerPosition.contains("oint"))
    this.positionNumber = 1;
    else if(playerPosition.contains("hoot"))
    this.positionNumber = 2;
    else if(playerPosition.contains("mall"))
    this.positionNumber = 3;
    else if(playerPosition.contains("ower"))
    this.positionNumber = 4;
    else if(playerPosition.contains("enter"))
    this.positionNumber = 5;
}
public void setPositionNumber(int thePositionNumber)
{
    this.positionNumber = thePositionNumber;
    switch(thePositionNumber){
    case 1: setPosition("Point Guard");
            break;
    case 2: setPosition("Shooting Guard");
            break;
    case 3: setPosition("Small Forward");
            break;
    case 4: setPosition("Power Forward");
            break;
    case 5: setPosition("Center");
            break;          
                            }
}
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}
public String getPosition()
{
    return position;
}
public int getPositionNumber()
{
    return positionNumber;
}
public String getTeam()
{
    return team;
}
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    BasketBallPlayer objectToCompare;
    if(other != null && other.getClass() == getClass())
    objectToCompare = (BasketBallPlayer) other;
    else
    return false;
    return( 
    (getPositionNumber() == objectToCompare.getPositionNumber()) &&
    (getName() == objectToCompare.getName()) && 
    getTeam() == objectToCompare.getTeam()) ;
}
public String toString()
{
    if(getTeam().equals("Retired"))
    return  getName() + " is retired.";
    else
    return  getName()+ " plays for the " + getTeam();
}
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    // five basketball player objects
    BasketBallPlayer kobe = new BasketBallPlayer("Kobe Bryant",
                               "Shooting Guard", "Retired");
    BasketBallPlayer ben = new BasketBallPlayer(
                              "Ben Wallace", 5, "Retired");
    BasketBallPlayer otto = new BasketBallPlayer("Otto Porter", 3,
                                                "Wizards");
    BasketBallPlayer andre = new BasketBallPlayer("Andre Drummond",
                                      "Center", "Pistons");
    BasketBallPlayer thomas = new BasketBallPlayer("Isaiah Thomas",
                                             1, "Celtics");
    BasketBallPlayer isaiah = new BasketBallPlayer("Isaiah Thomas",
                                  "Point Guard", "Pistons");  
    // initialize LinkedList and add three players                                       
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.add(kobe); list.add(otto); 
    list.add(thomas); 
    // display the first one
    System.out.println("First player on the list");
    System.out.println(list.peek());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(kobe.getName() + 
    " is retired so let's remove him.");
    // remove object at index 0
    list.remove(0);
    System.out.println();
    // add andre to the top of the list
    list.addFirst(andre);
    // add ben to the end
    list.addLast(ben);
    System.out.println("New first player on the list");
    System.out.println(list.peek());
    // first create an Object[] which acts as a BasketBallPlayer[]
    System.out.println(
    "Any other retired players? Printing entire list:");
    // using toArray()
    Object[] other = list.toArray();
    for(Object player: other)
    // display each player in the array
    System.out.println(player);

    // demonstrate contains()
    if(list.contains(ben))
    list.remove(ben);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Let's remove the retired player");
    System.out.println("Is " + ben.getName() + 
    " still on the list?");
    if(list.contains(ben))
    System.out.println(ben.getName() + " is still on the list");
    else
    {
        System.out.println(ben.getName() + " is not on the list");
        System.out.println("How many players after removing? " 
        + list.size());
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(otto.getName() + " is " + 
    // demonstrate indexOf()
    (list.indexOf(otto) + 1) +  " on the list");
    // create an iterator
    ListIterator listIterator = list.listIterator();
    System.out.println("Printing list using iterator:");
    // print out the list using the iterator
    while(listIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Object player = listIterator.next();
        System.out.println(player);
    }

}
```

Comment: If, as you say, this is for an assignment, it is probably best that you get help only from your professors, course assistants, or other course documents as to avoid potential allegations of plagiarism.

Comment: @JohnGallagher no, it is okay to seek help here, as long as it is clearly stated that this is an assignment, so that people can recommend the right direction in which the solution can be found without giving actual code and so without actually doing the OP's homework.  See https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Fair enough, I did ask my instructor already but I don't understand his answer. He tole me that I need to use a second iterator because "sometimes updating with one iterator and trying to use that same iterator using hasNext() doesn't work." I don't understand his explanation though, where in my code do I use the iterator to update the list?

Comment: Sounds reasonable - just always best to air on the side of caution when it comes to stuff like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem with the standard collections in java (and also in C#) is that you may not modify them while iterating over them.

If no extra steps are taken, and if you are unlucky, you may get no exception, just erratic program behavior.  To remedy this, java does actually take an extra step: iterators actually check to make sure that you do not modify the collection while iterating, and throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` if you do so, as soon as possible after you do so.

This feature is called "fail-fast" iterators, that's a term you can look up.

So, from the moment you instantiate an iterator, until the moment you stop using it, you may not modify the collection from which the iterator was created.

Can you spot the place in your code where you do that?

<sub>Also, regarding what your professor said: either you did not understand what your professor said, or what they said is wrong.  Iterators that offer means of modifying the collection while iterating do actually work. For example, you can do `iterator.remove()` to remove the current element.  That works, because if you modify the collection via the iterator, then the iterator is in charge, so it can take whatever measures are necessary to prevent data corruption.  What does not work, is modifying the collection by invoking any mutator methods directly on the collection itself while an iterator is active on the collection, because in that case the iterator has no knowledge of the fact that the collection is being modified at the moment that the collection is modified. The iterator throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` later, when it gets invoked to do anything, and it finds out that the collection had been modified in the mean time.</sub>

Comment: A few more points worth noting: it would have been best if you had a) posted the smallest possible amount of code necessary to illustrate the problem, b) not complicated things with some "part 1" and "part 2" which are confusing and hard to track, and c) properly formatted your code. Please remember that for next time you post.

Comment: Great, I will make sure future posts are more concise. I edited my code so that the iterator is instantiated after I offer the objects. That fixed my error. Thanks for your helpful criticism and useful advice.

Comment: Exactly.  Cheers!